# Graph interpretation deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, recurrent-neural-network

i'm trying to build a model that classify sentences. i'm using a Reccurent neural network(RNN) model "GRUcell" and i have the following Graph. the loss function i'm using is cross entropy. 
can you please explain me why the loss after been close to 0 pick to 1 after each iterations?
i can't find any interpretation of this, thank you.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rljrj.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the information you have provided it looks like its going down at the end of a batch and again going back up at the start of the next batch. This can be due to a high learning rate with not enough decay over time. 
Try to tweak the parameters and see if that helps.

Cheers

Comment: thanks for your help, i'm using Adam optimizer with 0.001 learning rate. i think Adam optimizer can adjust the learning rate automatically. i will change learning rate to 0.0001 and see what happens.